# Excepción no controlada en MessageBox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Me ocurre la siguiente excepción y necesito capturarla,junto con su mensaje, para mostrar el mismo de manera informativa al usuario.

Ocurre cuando intento borrar un campo. El id de este campo es clave foránea en otra tabla, por lo cual tendría que eliminar primero donde el id esta como clave foránea antes que en la tabla donde esta como primaria.

El error es el conocido :

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint

Reitero, necesito capturar la excepción en un messageBOX, como podría hacerlo ?

Comment: En un bloque `try{}` y `catch(Error a capturar){}`

Answer (score 0):

Con este codigo puede darte resultado,

```
  try
            {
                if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
                {
                    objetask.CodTareas1 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
                    objetask.EliminarTarea();
                    MessageBox.Show("Eliminado correctamente");
                    ListarVista();

                }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Seleccione una fila ");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Elimine la(s) actividad referenciada a esta tarea");

            }
```